# JSONParser response from MySQL to android studio error?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, jsonparser

I am implementing Android application in android studio 2.2. And I am dealing with the MySQL database I have been able to add data in the database but the problem in response from JSON I can not get a response . can you help me  please ؟ and thank you  very much

JSONParser.java

```
 package com.example.nn.ma;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"utf-8"));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //  e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

add_info.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$response = array();
if(isset($_POST['number'])){
$number = $_POST['number'];
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO add_info (`number`) VALUES 
('$number')");
if($result){
    $response["value"]=1;

}else{
    $response["value"]=0;

}
   }else{
    $response["value"]=-1;

}

   echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

addInfo.java

```
public class addCarInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
EditText number;
JSONParser jsonParser;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String value;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_info);


    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    number=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.PNText);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new AddInfo().execute();
        }
    });

    jsonParser=new JSONParser();
}
class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    String numberr= number.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(addInfo.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("wait ...");
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        List<NameValuePair> list= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number",numberr));

        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://10.24.60.205/ma/add_Info.php","POST",list);
        try{
            if(jsonObject!=null && !jsonObject.isNull("value")){

                value=jsonObject.getString("value");
            }else{
                value="0";
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());

        }



        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if(value =="1"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "errorrrr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: add ur sample json response in ur question

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?  If not, now would be a good time to learn how to do this.

Comment: thank you very much